# In Netbeans, how do I type a non-existent method and have the method get generated automatically?

Tags: java, netbeans6.8, netbeans6.1

In other IDEs, I can type a method as if it existed, hit a key combination and the method is generated.

For example, I type:

```
public List<String> getIds() {
    int max = 4;
    return generateRandomArray(max);
}
```

As of now, the method `generateRandomArray` doesn't exist.

I then hit a key combination and it generates:

```
private List<String> generateRandomArray(int max) {
    return null;
}
```

How do I accomplish this in Netbeans without having to type the method manually?

Comment: What a time saver! I didn't know about this option in any IDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Press alt+enter to show the auto fix options. Then, select create method ... (which should be the only option in most cases).

Comment: alt+enter works with the specific example given.  However, it doesn't work in the following instance.

<code>
  public List<String> getIds() {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(generateRandomId());
        return list;
    }
</code>

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, there should be a little icon (with a lightbulb and red (!) ) on the left side of the text editor window, at the line that contains `return generateRandomArray(max);`

Click on it and click the option that reads:

> Create method generateRandomArray(int)
>   in MyPackage.MyClass.